# How to resolve Less error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, less

Getting generic javascript error. Not able to resolve it, Can someone point out what steps should I take to debug this bug?

Getting this error **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null** in `less.js` file. I have created angular application which has some javascript plugins, Less is one of them.

Answer (score 5):

You are attempting to access a property (like a child member) of a JS object, but the JS object you are trying to access it from has evaluated to `null`. Basically, if we refer to the JS object as `bob`, you are trying to make a call to `bob.1`. However `bob` does not have a property called `1`. In fact, `bob` does not have any properties: `bob` has evaluated to `null`.

When you make your call to `bob.1` the computer wants to look at `bob`'s lexical scope to find something in there called `1`. However when the computer actually looks at `bob` it finds that `bob`'s type is `null`, and therefore `bob` cannot have a property called `1`. It then tells you this through the error you received.

What you should do next is take a look at `less.js` and try to find a method called `promise`. Then look for any attempt to access a property called `1` from any object within that method. When you find the object from which you are trying to access the property `1`, you know that object is not being initialized for some reason. You should then look at how that object is supposed to be initialized in order to make any necessary corrections to your implementation or the `less.js` file itself.

Comment: Thanks @William for quick response. Actually I checked my code I am not accessing ```1``` property on any object. I checked my code thoroughly.

Comment: @LaxmiSalunkhe It could also be an element of an array, which are kinda sorta objects in JS. Are you attempting to access an array at index 1?

Comment: I am trying to access ```0``` index at one place in my code but not ```1```.

Comment: @LaxmiSalunkhe Hmmm...that's strange. I've gotten this error a lot and it's always been about accessing a property from a `null`. JavaScript sometimes reports errors in strange ways, so that array could still be what's causing the problem...but that is strange.

Comment: I will get back to you as soon as I resolve this bug. Thanks for your inputs. I am searching for the scenarios where there may be chance of accessing property on null object.

Comment: Since you mentioned Angular, I recently faced similar issue though not exactly the same. Mine was because of the angular 2 beta 7 and es-shim 0.33 library. Upgrading them to beta 13 and 0.35 respectively helped. You can find more details here - https://jaykhimani.blogspot.com/2016/04/angular-2-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror.html. Hope this helps.